# jQuery calling same function multiple times with different input to the same div name

Tags: jquery, function, html

OK, so I am using a jQuery plugin called CountUp:  http://blog.ogulcanorhan.com/weekend-project-jquery-countup-plugin/

The script is fairly simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#jq_count_up').countUp({'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': 'dd/mm/YYYY-hh:mm:ss'});
    });
```

So the jQuery takes a starting timestamp (dd/mm/YYYY-hh:mm:ss) and then returns the days, hours, minutes, seconds since the input timestamp above.  The result will be displayed in side a  tag, as shown below:

Simple enough and it works great if you are only using the code one time on the page.  I have multiple timestamps which I am wanting to apply this script to.  The application is an email queue of how long people have been waiting.  So to try to fix this, I dynamically generated the timestamp via PHP on the server side and I also changed the name of the div so that it was unique for each of the multiple timestamps.  For example, here is the output of my PHP:

....................

```
    </td><td>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#jq_count_up-4').countUp({'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': '04/12/2011-14:56:33'});
    });
</script>
<div id="jq_count_up-4"></div>
</td><td>
```

(then later on in the same HTML output:

```
</td><td>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#jq_count_up-2').countUp({'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': '04/12/2011-08:44:43'});
    });
</script>
<div id="jq_count_up-2"></div>
</td><td>
```

So notice that I did 2 things to try to fix this issue:

- I changed the name of the reference to the div name tag within the script (I think) from `'#jq_count_up-2'` to `'#jq_count_up-X'` where X is a unique number.
- I changed the name of the `<div id=>` tag so that it is unique as well, and is the same name as in #1 above.

So the result is that still only one of the timestamps works, and it is the last one on the page.....   Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like the plugin is designed to be used more than once on a page. jQuery plugins need to be designed with that specifically in mind (here's a brief introduction on [how to achieve multiple instances](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern/comment-page-1#comment-80951)). From the [plugin code](http://test.ogulcan.org/countup/jquery.countup.js) it appears that global variables are being set, so a second instance of the plugin will overwrite the counter in the first, etc.

You could either tweak the plugin to support multiple instances and send it back to the author (he'll love you) or find another one.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(document).ready(function()` only once and try looks like you are using this function more than once.

Comment: I am.  I am using the script multiple times.  So you are saying just to use the script once but use different div tag names?

Comment: put all these div's in one document ready function and try like this 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#jq_count_up-2').countUp({'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': '04/12/2011-08:44:43'});
 $('#jq_count_up-4').countUp({'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': '04/12/2011-14:56:33'});

    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to create multiple instances using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startClock(time,id) {
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setSeconds(myDate.getSeconds() - time);
        var prettyDate = ('0' + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + myDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + myDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + myDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
        $("#time"+id).countUp({'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': ''+prettyDate+''});
    }
</script>
```

And then in your HTML just feed the function the `time` and the `id` of that instance of the counter. This way, there are multiple timers that can start from different timestamp locations.